# Displaying JSON File in Google Map Window

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, get

I am trying to display a json file in a Google Map window.

Chrome's privacy policy makes it extremely complicated to display a local json file from within your own domain.

I have attempted to run a local webserver, serve up the file and make the AJAX call to localhost, using the $.getJSON method to display the information, internally.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Info windows</title>
        <style type="text/css">/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

          // This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
          // When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

          function initMap() {
            var hc = {lat: 40.4512, lng: -85.3700};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: hc
            });

    var obj = $.getJSON( "ajax/GeoObs.json", function( data ) {
      var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
      });

      $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: obj
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: hc,
              map: map,
              title: 'Hartford City'
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
          }
        </script><script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCz672JUYjod6zzfxnBg_rzBNsBfbbjpJc&callback=initMap">
        </script></body>
    </html>
```

This displays the marker and creates a window.  However, it does not display any data.

Comment: getJSON is asynchronous.  Use the data (create the marker/infowindow) in its callback method.

Comment: mmm...the `lat` for Australia should be -40 something as it is in the southern hemisphere and the `lat` should be positive as it is east of Greenwich; are you sure you got your coords right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fellow coders have already suggested, `getJSON` is asynchronous so you must take that into account before the `infowindow` can show its content. This is *another approach* you can take:

```
function initMap() {
 var hc = {lat: 40.4512, lng: -85.3700};
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 zoom: 4,
 center: hc
 });

 var obj = $.getJSON( "ajax/GeoObs.json", function( data ) {
 var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    });

 $( "<ul/>", {
 "class": "my-new-list",
  html: items.join( "" )
 }).appendTo( "body" );
});

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Simple Test"
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: hc,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hartford City'
  });
```

Then just add an `event listener` such as `bounds_changed` so that when the map loads up, the content inside the `infowindow` can get displayed:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function(){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}
```

[Here is a JSBIN to show how it works](https://jsbin.com/zazocop/edit?js,output)

Comment: This works - perfect, except I am unable to show the json data.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't I be able to pass the variable for 'obj' in the content for 'var infowindow'?

Comment: Well if you see the Bin I have created the content is set to a string just to test it. So it works. I do not know where is your object but the content parameter for the infowindow should be either a string or an HTML node.  Do not quote me on that because I am out and cannot check it. If my previous works, you know what to do...:) any other help beyond this point just let me know

Comment: Yes, the `content parameter` accepts either a `string` or a `DOM node`. [Take a look here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your responses.  Setting the obj variable to 'contentstring' makes sense.  I guess where I am struggling is extracting content from json to string.  The Google example shows text being read directly from a div container.

Comment: Hello, the first problem you had was solved. You can now show some content in your `infowindow`, which was something you were not able to do before. What are you asking for, right now..?  If you do not want accept my answer because it is not enough of an effort for you that is fine...The way I work is I solve a problem you pay...you have another problem and we solve it...you pay. This is how I work.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, rags2riches!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this; you're making an asynchronous AJAX request to read your json file.

However you then initialise the infowindow with its content immediately, i.e. before the ajax request will have had time to complete.

Move the code into the callback function that happens after the ajax request is finished, e.g.:

```
function initMap() {
    var hc = {
        lat: 40.4512,
        lng: -85.3700
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: hc
    });

    $.getJSON("ajax/GeoObs.json", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<ul>' + items.join("") + '</ul>'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: hc,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hartford City'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Duncan, I am not following you; how is the `infowindow` called immediately if he only sets its content and calls the `open() method` once the `click event` fires?

Comment: You set the content immediately when you create it. Meanwhile the ajax request to the json file probably still hasn't completed.  Even though you only open the infowindow in response the user's click, after the ajax response is completed, you've previously set the infowindow content (which will be `null`) at the very start.

Comment: I know the concept and mechanism behind JSON/Ajax request so just wanted to clarify the meaning behind your previous comment. Thanks